# Can't delete a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using core data in my project, and In one of my table views im populating the cells with some objects I have.

The first cell in this table view is an object I want to delete based this object 'status' attribue. So in another view controller im changing to the first object at the table the 'status' to '1', and I want to be able to delete the cell visually but not the core data object.

So now my commitEditingStyle method looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        target.status = @1;
        CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
        [[stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target] ;
        [stack saveContext];


    }

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [self fetchData];
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }

}
```

currently as you see I'm deleting the record from the stack, What I though I can do is to delete those rows:

```
CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
 [[stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target] ;
 [stack saveContext];
```

and now I will not delete the record but the cell will be deleted.
Now the weird thing (to me) is when I delete those lines I'm not deleting the record but the cell is not deleted either...I dont get why with those lines the cell deleted...isn't those lines only deleting a record..?

Thanks

didDeleteObject method:

```
- (void)didDeleteObject {

    self.homeLabel.text = stackTableViewController.currentTarget;
    self.homeLabel.frame = homeLabelRect;
    for(int i = 40; i>5; i--){
        CGRect labelRect = [self.homeLabel.text
                            boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                            attributes:@{
                                         NSFontAttributeName : self.homeLabel.font
                                         }
                            context:nil];
        if(labelRect.size.height < self.homeLabel.frame.size.height){
            self.homeLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:i];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code of `didDeleteObject` method.

Comment: @Gandalf done. (its in another vc since its a delegate method)

Comment: Ok, to be honest i was hoping that you were reloading table data in this method. But as you are not so it's of no help. But let me give you few pointers: - 1) In your approach you are deleting record and then you must be reloading table data after fetchData which will automatically delete the row as no of records are less by one. That's why row is deleted. __@Solution__ - Maintain a local array for records and when deleting a cell, remove that object from array and reload table. Follow this [Link](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/delete-rows-from-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

I see you use NSFetchedResultController on your code.

NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate methods work together deleting UITableViewCell.

Please check your code NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate methods called.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```